# Cant run Terminal (fn f5 command) in Visual Studio (Running Parallels on a Mac OSX El Capitan)

Tags: c#

I am trying to run some C# code in Visual Studio (Running Parallels on a Mac OSX El Capitan) every time I press fn f5 the console comes up for second and then disappears...can some plz help.

Comment: Do you have an endless loop at the end to prevent returning?

Comment: To extend @jolati's question, you could do this by adding `Console.ReadKey()` to the end of your console application

Comment: Not sure about the endless loop how would  I check?

Comment: i am testing with this   Console.WriteLine("Hello world"); then hitting fn f5...where would I put console.readkey()?

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys